# IF(Logical_test) values for multiple

Tags: excel, if-statement, infinite

I've been using this in my workbook to show `cefor` multiple values function.

```
=IF(E6=B4,C4,IF(E6=B5,C5,IF(E6=B6,C6,IF(E6=B7,!C7,IF(E6=B8,C8,IF(E6=B9,C9,
IF(E6=B10,C10,IF(E6=B11,!C11,IF(E6=B12,C12,IF(E6=B13,C13,IF(E6=B14,C14,IF(E6=B15,C15,))))))))))))
```

Yeah, it's too simple...at least it's working...

Until recently, I faced problem on updating and adding much more values into the table....(the tables going further till `B200` and `C200`)

Need help to make the formula simpler, for infinite loop....

Thanks.

Comment: So are you finding 'the first match' with E6? Then how about to search or lookup?

Answer (score 2):

Your formula looks as if the requirement is:

Look for the `E6` value in column `B`, starting with `B4`, and get back the appropriate value from column `C`.

This is the use case of the [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function.

So:

```
=VLOOKUP(E6, B4:C200, 2, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex Richter has provided the `vlookup` solution.  This is an alternative approach to vlookup.  It will do the same job, but is not as restrictive in the layout of the data that vlookup requires.

```
=index(C:C,match(E6,B:B,0))
```